# Having trouble with if/else

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm having trouble with a part of my code. If I pick option A it runs and gives me the correct answer, however, if I pick option S or M it gives me nothing and only goes to where it's supposed to go. Already tried changing the if's for else if's but it says "expected statement".

Sorry if some sentences are in portuguese but here it is:

```
if ((opcao2 == 'A') || (opcao2 == 'a'))
                {
                    if ((LinhaA != LinhaB) && (ColunaA != ColunaB))     //confirmar que se pode fazer a subtraçao entre as duas matrizes
                    {
                        printf("\nN%co %c poss%cvel somar as matrizes A + B!\nInsira novos valores\n", 198, 130, 161);
                        fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\nNão é possível somar as matrizes A + B!\nInsira novos valores\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n\n\n");
                    fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\n\n");

                    if ((LinhaA == LinhaB) && (ColunaA == ColunaB))
                    {
                        printf("\n%c poss%cvel somar as matrizes A + B!\n", 144, 161);
                        fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\nÉ possível somar as matrizes A + B!\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n\n\n");
                    fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\n\n");
                }
                break;

             if ((opcao2 == 'S') || (opcao2 == 's'))

                    {

                    if((LinhaA != LinhaB) && (ColunaA != ColunaB))      //confirmar que se pode fazer a subtraçao entre as duas matrizes

                    {
                        printf("\nN%co %c poss%cvel somar as subtrair A - B!\nInsira novos valores\n", 198, 130, 161);
                        fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\nNão é possível subtrair as matrizes A - B!\nInsira novos valores\n");
                    }

                    printf("\n\n\n");
                    fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\n\n");

                    else if ((LinhaA == LinhaB) && (ColunaA == ColunaB))
                    {
                        printf("\n%c poss%cvel subtrair as matrizes A - B!\n", 144, 161);
                        fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\nÉ possível subtrair as matrizes A - B!\n");
                    }

                    printf("\n\n\n");
                    fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\n\n");
                }
                break;

                if ((opcao2 == 'M') || (opcao2 == 'm'))

                {
                    if (ColunaA != LinhaB)      //confirmar que se pode fazer a multiplicação entre as duas matrizes
                    {
                        printf("\nN%co %c poss%cvel multiplicar as matrizes A * B!\nInsira novos valores\n", 198, 130, 161);
                        fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\nNão é possível multiplicar as matrizes A * B!\nInsira novos valores\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n\n\n");
                    fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n\n\n");

                    if (ColunaA == LinhaB);

                    printf("\n%c poss%cvel multiplicar as matrizes A * B!\n", 144, 161);
                    fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\nÉ possível multiplicar as matrizes A * B!\n");

                    fprintf(ficheiro_out, "\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: If the `if` statements are in a `loop` and using `break` is a MUST, then you better include them with in the braces.

Comment: I think your confusing the syntax of a switch statement with else/if statements by using the term break instead of else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` statements are clearly sending program control to beyond the final `if` `else` block.

use `} else if {` instead and drop the `break` statements completely.

Comment: Now would also be a good time to learn how to use a line by line debugger. It would have been obvious with such a thing.

Comment: It's a new programming class that started not to long ago, and the teacher wants to rush this stuff, so he doesn't teach that kind of stuff. Guess it's time for some self teaching.

Comment: @LuisCardo: Indeed it is. Learning to use a debugger is more important than learning to code.